# Elegant way to handle strings, multi-line-strings and lists in Python

Tags: python, string, list, multiline

I've got a custom log function in Python and I'd like to have a Pythonic way to split the input in multiple lines. The input could be a string, a multi-line-string or a list.

This works well for strings and multi-line-strings, however it doesn't handle lists:

```
def log( text, indent = 0):
    indent_level = 4
    current_time = str( datetime.datetime.now().time())[0:-3]
    for line in text.splitlines():
        log_line = current_time + ' | ' + indent_level * indent * ' ' + str( line)
        print( log_line)
```

What do you suggest to also be able to handle lists without complex

```
if( type( string) == list):
```

tests all over the place?

Comment: Why don't you know what the inputs are?

Comment: Can the list format contain elements with multiple lines?  Also, have you looked at the built in logging module?

Comment: @phant0m:
The input of this function are either strings I write to know where I am or return codes from other functions. These return codes can be simple line strings, multi line strings of lists (or even something else).

Comment: @sr2222:
Thanks for the suggestion but so far I haven't had time to conquer the logging module.

Comment: off topic:
I couldn't find any information in FAQs, why politeness in posts is not approved, like "Hello" and "Thank you very much!"!?!?

Comment: @asklucas: There is a discussion of this on [meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: @unutbu
Thanks for the link! Uhm, sorry for thanking you!!!
But is there an official conclusion by board owners of is it more of an edit war like in German forums or the German Wikipedia?

Comment: @unutbu Also clarified: Mr. Atwood is the boss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use duck typing to normalize the input once, at the beginning of the method.

```
try:
    # Assume you get multiline text
    lines = text.splitlines()
except AttributeError:
    # If your assumption was wrong, then you should already have a list
    lines = text
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll investigate this!
So far I used .splitlines(), but for lists it didn't throw an exception.

Comment: If you actually have a `list`, it will raise an `AttributeError` if you try to call `splitlines()` on it.

Comment: You're right! Sorry for the stupid question: I just found out some bugs in my source that caused this to "appear like a list". But it wasn't! Thanks to you I also understand the term Duck Typing!!!